# Calculate mean by selecting only some rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(43.8735370052414, 43.2134452032708, 46.3127470212784, 
47.9401589009531, 30.5684881461115, 32.5528665575571, 29.3035738750668, 
30.9770316442935), Author = c("Arthur", "Mario", "ALPACA_M_19", 
"ALPACA_M_27", "Arthur", "Mario", "ALPACA_M_19", "ALPACA_M_27"
), Distance = c("G-RHI", "G-RHI", "G-RHI", "G-RHI", "NS-RHI", 
"NS-RHI", "NS-RHI", "NS-RHI"), Skull = c("W003", "W003", "W003", 
"W003", "W004", "W004", "W004", "W004")), row.names = c(NA, -8L
), class = "data.frame")
```

This `df` has this view:

```
> df
        V1      Author Distance Skull
1 43.87354      Arthur    G-RHI  W003
2 43.21345       Mario    G-RHI  W003
3 46.31275 ALPACA_M_19    G-RHI  W003
4 47.94016 ALPACA_M_27    G-RHI  W003
5 30.56849      Arthur   NS-RHI  W004
6 32.55287       Mario   NS-RHI  W004
7 29.30357 ALPACA_M_19   NS-RHI  W004
8 30.97703 ALPACA_M_27   NS-RHI  W004
```

By using next code, I can create two extra columns with the mean value per Distance and Skull:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Skull, Distance) %>%
  mutate(Mean = mean(V1))

# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   Skull, Distance [2]
     V1 Author      Distance Skull  Mean
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
1  43.9 Arthur      G-RHI    W003   45.3
2  43.2 Mario       G-RHI    W003   45.3
3  46.3 ALPACA_M_19 G-RHI    W003   45.3
4  47.9 ALPACA_M_27 G-RHI    W003   45.3
5  30.6 Arthur      NS-RHI   W004   30.9
6  32.6 Mario       NS-RHI   W004   30.9
7  29.3 ALPACA_M_19 NS-RHI   W004   30.9
8  31.0 ALPACA_M_27 NS-RHI   W004   30.9
```

However, I would like to create a new column with the Mean values of only Arthur and Mario, that applies to the other.

In other words, an output similar to this one (new column `Mean_A_M`):

```
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   Skull, Distance [2]
     V1 Author      Distance Skull  Mean  Mean_A_M
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    <chr> <dbl>  
1  43.9 Arthur      G-RHI    W003   45.3  43.55
2  43.2 Mario       G-RHI    W003   45.3  43.55
3  46.3 ALPACA_M_19 G-RHI    W003   45.3  43.55
4  47.9 ALPACA_M_27 G-RHI    W003   45.3  43.55
5  30.6 Arthur      NS-RHI   W004   30.9  31.6
6  32.6 Mario       NS-RHI   W004   30.9  31.6
7  29.3 ALPACA_M_19 NS-RHI   W004   30.9  31.6
8  31.0 ALPACA_M_27 NS-RHI   W004   30.9  31.6
```

As you can see, averages in `Mean_A_M` are calculated based only on Arthur and Mario rows, per skull and distance.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%in%` you can filter for the authors you want to include when computing the mean:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
df %>%
  group_by(Skull, Distance) %>%
  mutate(
    Mean = mean(V1),
    Mean_A_M = mean(V1[Author %in% c("Arthur", "Mario")])
  )
#> # A tibble: 8 × 6
#> # Groups:   Skull, Distance [2]
#>      V1 Author      Distance Skull  Mean Mean_A_M
#>   <dbl> <chr>       <chr>    <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1  43.9 Arthur      G-RHI    W003   45.3     43.5
#> 2  43.2 Mario       G-RHI    W003   45.3     43.5
#> 3  46.3 ALPACA_M_19 G-RHI    W003   45.3     43.5
#> 4  47.9 ALPACA_M_27 G-RHI    W003   45.3     43.5
#> 5  30.6 Arthur      NS-RHI   W004   30.9     31.6
#> 6  32.6 Mario       NS-RHI   W004   30.9     31.6
#> 7  29.3 ALPACA_M_19 NS-RHI   W004   30.9     31.6
#> 8  31.0 ALPACA_M_27 NS-RHI   W004   30.9     31.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ave`

```
> transform(df, 
+           mean=ave(V1, Skull, Distance, FUN=mean),
+           mean_am=ave(V1, Skull, Distance, 
+                       FUN=\(x) mean(x[Author %in% c('Arthur', 'Mario')], na.rm=TRUE)))
        V1      Author Distance Skull     mean  mean_am
1 43.87354      Arthur    G-RHI  W003 45.33497 43.54349
2 43.21345       Mario    G-RHI  W003 45.33497 43.54349
3 46.31275 ALPACA_M_19    G-RHI  W003 45.33497 43.54349
4 47.94016 ALPACA_M_27    G-RHI  W003 45.33497 43.54349
5 30.56849      Arthur   NS-RHI  W004 30.85049 31.56068
6 32.55287       Mario   NS-RHI  W004 30.85049 31.56068
7 29.30357 ALPACA_M_19   NS-RHI  W004 30.85049 31.56068
8 30.97703 ALPACA_M_27   NS-RHI  W004 30.85049 31.56068
```